# Oracle Overloaded methods are not supported

Tags: c#, oracle, overloading

I'm using .Net C# to call an Oracle function using the usual Oracle command object.
In the Oracle package there is a procedure called SetNullHandling and also a function by the same name.  The function is the method I'm calling passing in some XML, and this in turn calls the procedure.

```sql
procedure SetNullHandling(pNullHandling integer) is...

function SetNullHandling(pInput in XMLType) return XMLType is...
```

When I try and execute my C# code passing in an XML type, I get an error.

```
{"Overloaded methods are not supported (PX_Package.SetNullHandling)"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is generating that exception - is it coming from the driver you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If overloading isn't supported, you'll need a wrapper procedure/function to call the overloaded variant, e.g. FSetNullHandling to wrap the SetNullHanlding FUNCTION and PSetNullNullHanlding for the proc, then call these wrappers in the C#.

Answer (score 0):

Got the DBA's to rename the function so it is now unique.  Worked around the problem.